# Laravel controller method not found

Tags: php, laravel-4

Trying to run the following Laravel 4.1 route: `http://myserver.dev/admin/import-items/1`

When I do so, I get the following error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException
Controller method not found.
```

Here are my routes for this:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin', 'before' => 'auth'), function()
{
    Route::get('items/import-items/{after?}', array('as' => 'importItems', 'uses' => 'ItemsController@importItems'));

    Route::get('items/{id}/show', 'ItemsController@show');
    Route::resource('items', 'ItemsController');
});
```

I can look at the Items controller, and the method `importItems` is most definitely there:

```
class ItemsController extends \BaseController {

    /**
     * Item Model
     * @var Item
     */
    protected $item;

    /**
     * Inject the models.
     * @param Item $item
     */
    public function __construct(Item $item)
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->item = $item;
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of items
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index($items = [])
    {
        $title = Lang::get('admin/items/title.manage_items');

        if (empty($items))
            $items = $this->item;

        return View::make('admin/items/index', compact('items', 'title'));
    }

    /**
     * Imports Items after specified date.
     * @return array
     **/
    public function importItems($after = 7)
    {

        $results = Item::importItems($after);

        return $results;
    }
}
```

When I run `php artisan routes` the route clearly shows up as usable in the list:

```
GET|HEAD admin/items/import-items/{after?} | importItems   | ItemsController@importItems
```

The thing is, this exact code works just fine from another project I had it in. After I copied over the route settings and the controller and model, it decided not to work in this new project. I feel like I've missed some key step here because I can't see any differences in the code.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please post `ItemsController`

Comment: Have you run `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: Yes, ran `composer dump-autoload` but did not fix. Added `ItemsController` to post.

Comment: Try `\ItemsController@show`

Comment: @AmitGarg Same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong url. This url:

```
http://myserver.dev/admin/import-items/1
```

should be this instead

```
http://myserver.dev/admin/items/import-items/1
```

**OR**

```
Route::get('items/import-items/{after?}', array('as' => 'importItems', 'uses' => 'ItemsController@importItems'));
```

should be

```
Route::get('import-items/{after?}', array('as' => 'importItems', 'uses' => 'ItemsController@importItems'));
```

...depends which url you want

Comment: Absolutely amazing. And by amazing, I mean "face palm". It all boiled down to the link I had embedded in a view that was wrong in the new code and correct in the old. Thanks for catching this!! :)